# Convert to directed graph to undirected graph in Python igraph

Tags: python, graph-theory, igraph

I am attempting to draw an undirected graph in iGraph, but the graph I draw seems to have little arrows on it still. Is it possible to convert the directed graph object to an undirected graph object, so that the arrows are gone?

**Here's my code:**

```
import igraph
import cairo
import igraph
graph = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('network.txt')
igraph.plot(graph)
```

**network.txt =**

```
1 2
2 1
2 3
2 7
3 1
4 2
4 6
5 4
5 6
7 4
7 8
8 9
9 7
10 7
10 8
10 9
11 2
1 2
3 4
5 8
12 3
1 1
```

Comment: `Graph.Read_Ncol()` has a `directed=...` keyword argument that lets igraph know whether the graph you are loading is directed or undirected (since the NCOL format does not specify it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented here: http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html

There are functions:

```
to_directed()
to_undirected()
```

Depending on which way you want to go (it isn't clear to me from the title).

Comment: I think this scrambles some of the vertices' and edges' labels. It's best just to import it using the keyword mentioned by @Tamás.